# Overflow 6 error when returning recordset from function

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

My function takes in parameters and executes a sql query, returning the recordset, but it's erroring on the return.

```
Public Function ExecuteParameters(sql As String, ParamArray Params() As Variant) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim inputParam As Variant
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Procs.getConn
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    For Each inputParam In Params
        Set inputParam = cmd.CreateParameter(, GetParameterType(inputParam), adParamInput, Len(Nz(inputParam, " ")), inputParam)
        cmd.Parameters.Append inputParam
    Next inputParam

    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    'errors out on this line
    Set ExecuteParameters = cmd.Execute()
End Function
```

This code works fine until the line returning the recordset out of the function, it errors out as `overflow`. I got this code from a tutorial and can't figure out what the problem is, so any help appreciated.

Function is called from here:

```
Public Function OnDelete()
    ExecuteParameters "DELETE * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?", "Students", "StudentID", 32
End Function
```

Comment: Could you update your question to show how you call this function.  Also, I would suggest verifying the Params.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of struggling over this, someone finally pointed out that only actual values can be passed as parameters, not table or column names. The problem was in the function call, not in the return as I originally thought.

**Updated code:**

```
Public Function OnDelete()
    ExecuteParameters "DELETE * FROM Students WHERE StudentID = ?", 32
End Function
```

Hope this saves someone the time it took me...